# amp-list to render different elements based on Json value

Tags: amp-html, amp-list

I have an amp-list that outputs bunch of divs nice and easy, my only problem is that I want the first output item to have some different attributes from others.

Here's an example:

```
<amp-list layout="responsive" width="40" height="67" src="someurl"  items="." single-item=".">
 <template type="amp-mustache">  
     {{#NewsPaperPages}}
        <div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="{{PageNum}}" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0"></div>
      {{/NewsPaperPages}}
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

which renders to this:

```
<div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="1" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0"></div>
<div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="2" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0"></div>
<div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="3" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0"></div>
```

But I'd like the first item to be :

```
<div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="1" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0" selected ></div>
```

where `aria-selected` is set to `true` and `selected` attribute has added

Answer (score 0):

In your `amp-list` JSON file, add a key/value pair in the usual format such as `"aria":" "`.

For the item, set the value, such as `"aria":"true"`

Then set your `amp-mustache` processor like this:

`<div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="{{PageNum}}" aria-selected="{{aria}}" tabindex="0">`